# what's the state of go language IDE support?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide, intellij-idea, go

Can anyone share his experience working with go in one of the three java IDE giants -I mean eclipse, netbeans and JIdea

--

there's a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737098/is-there-an-ide-for-go but I think it's a little outdated, almost a year ago...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a page at http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/ which describes methods for getting various text editors and IDEs, including Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA, to play nicely with Go. Both GEdit and Vim have decent support, having defined methods for integration with GoCode, a code completion daemon, and syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6):

There's this: http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/, but it's in the alpha stages of development. Could do with a little bit of love.

Answer (score 6):

Vim, Emacs or LiteIDE http://code.google.com/p/golangide/